# Maven archive in .m2 doesn't install dependencies

Tags: java, spring, maven

I've downloaded an existing project from our Github repository into my local drive.

However, when I run the command:

`mvn clean install -U`

it throws some compile errors due to a missing dependency.

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/analyticsDev/dev3/dashboard/src/main/java/com/sick/dd/controller/DashboardController.java:[945,59] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method isValidFileName(java.lang.String)
  location: class com.sick.ap.components.filemanager.util.FileUtils
[ERROR] /C:/analyticsDev/dev3/dashboard/src/main/java/com/sick/dd/controller/DashboardController.java:[948,68] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable INVALID_FILENAME
  location: class com.sick.ap.components.loginmodule.settings.configuration.constant.ApLoginUserConstants
[INFO] 2 errors
```

I retried by deleting the relevant dependency from my local .m2 directory, but the dependency did not re-appear and the compile failed with the same error.

I checked the source for the component causing the error in github, and it's up-to-date, so that's not the problem.

Here's the relevant .m2 directory component:

[image]

As you can see, the date of the entry is from late November, i.e. not today. That's probably because I ran a `mvn clean install -U` on the actual project on that date.

The point of maven is to handle the dependencies for you. Any idea why this isn't happening here?

Here's a typical extract from the output of the `mvn clean install -U` command. I can't give it all because it exceeds the posting limit. Note that the access to metadata.xml message are warnings which it always gives in other projects and don't prevent the compile:

```
https://artifactory.sick.com:443/artifactory/gbc05-gus-rpc-bip-releases-maven-local/com/sick/bip/i18nl10n/1.6.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml , ReasonPhrase:.
[WARNING] Failure to transfer com.sick.bip:i18nl10n:1.6.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from https://artifactory.sick.com:443/artifactory/gbc05-gus-rpc-bip-snapshots-maven-local/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of gbc05-gus-rpc-bip-snapshots-maven-external has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata com.sick.bip:i18nl10n:1.6.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to gbc05-gus-rpc-bip-snapshots-maven-external (https://artifactory.sick.com:443/artifactory/gbc05-gus-rpc-bip-snapshots-maven-local/): Access denied to: https://artifactory.sick.com:443/artifactory/gbc05-gus-rpc-bip-snapshots-maven-local/com/sick/bip/i18nl10n/1.6.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml , ReasonPhrase:.
[WARNING] Failure to transfer com.sick.bip:i18nl10n:1.6.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from https://artifactory.sick.com:443/artifactory/gbc05-gus-rpc-pa-product-maven-local/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of gbc05-gus-rpc-pa-product-maven-external has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata com.sick.bip:i18nl10n:1.6.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to gbc05-gus-rpc-pa-product-maven-external (https://artifactory.sick.com:443/artifactory/gbc05-gus-rpc-pa-product-maven-local/): Access denied to: https://artifactory.sick.com:443/artifactory/gbc05-gus-rpc-pa-product-maven-local/com/sick/bip/i18nl10n/1.6.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml , ReasonPhrase:.
[WARNING] Failure to transfer com.sick.bip:i18nl10n:1.6.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from https://artifactory.sick.com:443/artifactory/gbc05-gus-rpc-bip-releases-maven-local/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of gbc05-gus-rpc-bip-releases-maven-external has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata com.sick.bip:i18nl10n:1.6.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to gbc05-gus-rpc-bip-releases-maven-external (https://artifactory.sick.com:443/artifactory/gbc05-gus-rpc-bip-releases-maven-local/): Access denied to: https://artifactory.sick.com:443/artifactory/gbc05-gus-rpc-bip-releases-maven-local/com/sick/bip/i18nl10n/1.6.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml , ReasonPhrase:.
```

Comment: This does not look like a maven dependency error, more like a compiler error. Can you post more context from the log? Normally if you miss a dependency Maven tells you which group id and artifact id it cannot download and from which URL.

Comment: A wild guess, maybe the state of the latest code in the master branch does not compile. Should you check out a specific tag or branch (for example, the latest release version) in order to compile? In order to say for sure, we would need more context.

Comment: It's most likely not a compile issue - I checked the source in github and the variable was there.

Comment: Your log literally says `[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR`.

Comment: I'll post some context - note there are a lot of metadata.xml *warnings*, but these are normal and I don't get the compile errors.

Comment: Yes, it's getting a compile error because the repository isn't reflecting code that exists in github.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239996/discussion-between-roccobaroccosc-and-jack-benimble).

Answer (score 0):

The error log you uploaded is quite explicit (I removed some text to make the error apparent):

```
[WARNING] Failure to transfer ... from https://artifactory.sick.com:443/.... 
was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of gbc05-gus-rpc-bip-snapshots-maven-external has elapsed or updates are forced. 
Original error: Could not transfer metadata ... from/to gbc05-gus-rpc-bip-snapshots-maven-external (https://artifactory.sick.com:443/....): 
Access denied to: https://artifactory.sick.com:443/artifactory/..... , ReasonPhrase:.
```

In the recent past your maven had an error "Access denied" to your Nexus repository and this was cached, so now when you execute the Maven command it fails with the cached error.
You are using `-U` so this should force a download but to be sure, you could remove your `~/.m2/repository` and try again.

And you need to figure out why your access to these URLs is denied? Try to load the Nexus in the browser and see if it works there.

I think the main issue is that your Maven cached an older version and is unable to download the currently deployed artifact, so it uses the local ones as a fallback, but they contain code that does not compile. So in a sense, it IS a dependency issue but Maven shows it as a compilation issue.

Comment: I deleted .m2, but this time it fails on the on the first company platform component not found, and the new m2 directory shows no company assets. I know it points to an access denied issue, and I will check that tomorrow with the admin. I've been getting these access denied errors for a while, and the admin says I have full access. When I tried to log in just now via the URL from the output, it showed invalid username/password. It's pretty frustrating but this is a good chance to get to the bottom of this, since its a new project.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense. You probably cached the artifacts a while ago and continued working with obsolete code but now you get to the first big incompatibilities and the first compilation errors. Maybe you just need fresh credentials and it will work out.

Comment: Yeah, I hope so. I wasn't working with obsolete code, I was downloading the source for the dependencies and recompiling it locally. I'd rather not have to do that. I will let you know, and accept the answer assuming that is in fact the issue.